# Why does my app only appear in the Android play store when I don't enter spaces

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just uploaded an up to the playstore but can only find it if I don't enter spaces. From my understanding the search in the playstore is based off the package name.

my package for example is:

```
businessdomain.actualappname
```

in the play store I can find it by:

```
businessdomain
actualappname
```

But I want to find it using just:

```
actual app name
```

or possibly

```
actualappname
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about behaviour of the search engine in play store.

Comment: in your config.xml file  you will see one property `<name>XXX</name>`..when you search in android store by entering that name you will find that app

Comment: @Anilkumar Thank you for the respnse, the property tag has spaces in it

Comment: you can write your own name .. that name will corresponds to the name of the app when a user is trying to fetch .. once change the name & upload that apk file in android store and search it .. than you will find the results